# join3 tables with unequal row and columns not matching

Tags: sql

I have three tables from which I need to create a single table. Table1 and table 2 have columns in common which is col1 which is an id. where col1 of table 1 is equal to col1 of table 2 we need to fetch the data for the output table and add col9 to each row in output table.

Table 1

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 
a12  abc  usa  dol
b12  def  In   inr
c12  ghi  Uk   gbp
```

Table2

```
col1 col5 col6
a12  586  svc
b12  596  swf
c12  600  chl
d12  897  svc
e12  912  swf
```

table3

```
col7 col8    clo9
1.1  21/6/17  test1
```

output table

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col6 col7 col9
a12  abc  usa  dol  586  svc  test1
b12  def  In   inr  596  swf  test1
c12  ghi  Uk   gbp  600  chl  test1
```

Comment: Can you also share with us what you have tried so far to solve the problem?

Comment: @shubha integrate this script in your query

Comment: @Giorgos, I tried inner join for table1 and table 2 but I am unable to join table 3 as it has no common column and unequal rows. I tried union to join col9 from table 3 but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

based on your table using CROSS APPLY we can achieve :

```
;WITH CTE AS (
select T.col1, col2, col3, col4,TT.col1 As TTcol, col5, col6 from Table1 T
INNER JOIN Table2 TT
On T.col1 = TT.col1 )

Select * from  CTE 
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT   m.col9
        FROM    Table3 m

        ) q
```